# If the website owner steals the payment gateway information then is it safe to use a payment gateway?

Tags: asp.net, authorize.net

I am integrating a payment gateway; this is the first time I am integrating payment gateway functionality to my system, I am using Authorised.Net for the payment gateway.

As I have successfully integrated it but I see the user has to enter the following values to purchase his item, and the transaction id is returned.

```
    //post_values.Add("x_card_num", "4111111111111111");
    //post_values.Add("x_card_num", CreditCard);
    //post_values.Add("x_exp_date", "0115");
    ////post_values.Add("x_amount", "19.99");
    ////post_values.Add("x_amount", );
    ////post_values.Add("x_description", "Sample Transaction");
    //post_values.Add("x_amount", txtAmout.Text);

    //post_values.Add("x_description", txtDesc.Text);

    ////post_values.Add("x_first_name", "John");
    ////post_values.Add("x_last_name", "Doe");
    ////post_values.Add("x_address", "1234 Street");
    ////post_values.Add("x_state", "WA");
    ////post_values.Add("x_zip", "98004");
    //post_values.Add("x_first_name", txtFName.Text);
    //post_values.Add("x_last_name", txtFName.Text);
    //post_values.Add("x_address", txtAddr.Text);
    //post_values.Add("x_state", txtState.Text);
    //post_values.Add("x_zip", txtZip.Text);
```

These values just fix his transaction and purchase of item, so my confusion is that if the web site owner put all this information into his database and made more transactions using his details, then what? Is it safe and secure, or something else happens that I could not figure out?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Are you asking about the website owner using the information in the future without the customer's knowledge or are you asking about storing the information for future transactions?

Comment: i am asking how safe it is, if the website owner saves his card details to a DB and purchase the items with his details then what/;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it is, website owner can put all the information into his database, if the transaction mode is present on the website, thats why I and I think most of others either do transactions from trusted sites or sites that redirect to some trusted gateway like paypal or authorize.net for financial transactions.

Comment: i am using Authorised.net and it is seamless...A seamless payment gateway is one that processes credit cards directly on your online shop website without redirecting the purchasing customer to any 3rd party website

Comment: Yeh I know, we also recently used Authroised.Net in one of our projects and we took the input from user and saved it in database, we also saved the credit card number but like ************1111, only last four digits. You can use this approach as well if you have to show CC number in some report to customer. <br>Also you will have to either implement SSL on your website or you can redirect customer to Authorize.NET and after the transaction they will send him back to you. Second is better approach if site needs to gain trust of customers.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some basic guidelines to follow:

1. Keep all information in your database except for the credit number. Never keep the credit number unless you feel that your encryption systems are safe.
2. Store Authorize.net successful or failed transactions
3. You need to create a transaction table where you will create a new line for each transaction, regardless of being the same user, or transaction result.
4. Encrypt some portions of the transaction: Address is good thing to encrypt. This will avoid identity theft if you ever get hacked.
5. Make sure all user passwords are hashed
6. Store the Web Site Database connection encrypted as well
7. Communicate with the database using only stored procedures. This should avoid SQL injection, if the stored procedures are built correctly.

Comment: But my question is what if database owner himself mis use the details, how safe it is that a user put his card number and other details as i mentioned above to the site, of payment getway has some mechanism that recognize it that it from user only not from any other, or this the client has to do on the trust basis..

Comment: Authorize.net has several features that will help authorize transactions which include credit card number, Card Verification Code, Location of the web site (USA, or Eastern Europe (most likely blocked)), etc. But any web site owner who stores this information can use it. Once you have the information in your hands it works on pure trust basis.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clarification. I'm currently working on a project that is using PayPal in this same manner. We store **only** the authorization code and transaction ID in our database.

In my opinion, the 30 seconds or so that the user will save by having their information stored isn't worth the risk associated with storing their information. If you're doing recurring transactions, the vendor will store the information securely for you (at least PayPal does) so there's no real reason to store the credit card information in your system.

[EDIT] As Imran pointed out, storing the last 4 digits of the number would be fine for display on a report.

You can do nothing to prevent the DB owner from misusing the information if they're storing it aside from contacting your credit card company and reporting fraudulent charges. The payment gateway has no idea who is inputting the payment details, other than ensuring the transaction is coming from one of their authorized customers (i.e., the customer authorized to use the payment gateway).

Comment: yes i understand it is worth less to store credit card information in DB, i am doing the same i only saving trasationID and few more relevent details, but if some cheated or non credible website sells some item comes into the market and they have mechanism to save card info to DB then i want to know can they misuse it's info, the buyer totally unaware of it, that his card info is also saved..

Comment: It's data. If it's stored in their system they can do whatever they want with it until they get caught.

Comment: Thank you this was my confusion, no way to prevent it if owner misuse it, the legal process comes late in picture:)